# Calculate conditional density given joint pdf?

Tags: probability

$(x,y)$ is uniformly distributed on $\{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$: $x\geq y\}$, how to calculate $f(y|x)$? I think on the set, pdf is $f(x,y)=2$, but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you managed to find the marginal density of $x$? And do you know the formula for conditional density?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth marginal density is int f(x,y)dy, right?  And the formula is f(x|y)=f(x,y)/f_{y}(y)? Learned it long time ago, almost forget it all...

Comment: Yes. Here you want $f(y\mid x)$, which is $\dfrac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Is the answer f(y|x)=1/x  correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq x\leq 1}$, and so....

$$\begin{align}f_{Y}(y)&= \int_\Bbb R 2\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq x\leq 1}~\mathrm dx &&\text{by Law of Total Probability}\\[1ex]&=2\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}\int_y^1 ~\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=2(1-y)\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}\\[3ex] f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)&=\dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1}{1-y}\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq x\leq 1}\end{align}$$

Evaluate $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$ in a similar manner.